# On 'axiality' of planar convex regions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

Axiality has been studied under a definition given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiality_(geometry)

Consider an *alternative definition* of axiality as follows: For a convex region C, consider a chord L and the set of chords of C that are perpendicular to L. For each perpendicular chord, consider the ratio: length of smaller segment to length of larger segment into which L divides it. Now, for chord L, define an 'axiality ratio' as the *minimum* of these ratios over all its perpendicular chords. Now, the best axis of C is that chord for which axiality ratio is a *maximum* and that value of the axiality ratio could be called the axiality of C itself.

**Question:** What shape of C *minimizes* axiality under this new definition?

Note: Some more related thoughts are recorded at http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/01/axiality-of-planar-convex-regions.html and http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/01/centralness-of-convex-planar-regions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many bodies have vanishing axiality ratio.
Indeed, if the ratio for $L$ is positive, then the whole body projects to $L$.
So you may start with convex smooth body, locate these exceptional chords and modify the body in a small neighborhood of its ends making the ratio = zero.

In particular, you get a body with zero ratio arbitrarily close to any given body (in the sense of Hausdorff).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a serious problem with the definition - especially body C not projecting onto chord L. The following approach too appears to fail to capture the extent of axial symmetry: consider for each chord L, the *minimum* among all chords perpendicular to L of the ratio: *(larger segment length / smaller seg length)*, and then, take the *minimum* over all chords of this axiality ratio as the axiality of C itself.